# python strip() seems doesn't working as expected

Tags: python, string, removing-whitespace

I do my apologizes for the dummy question, but i'm experiencing a weird problem with a simple script that seems correct but doesnt' works as expected

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json,sys
obj=json.load(sys.stdin)
oem=obj["_id"]
models = obj.get("modelli", 0)

if models != 0:
        for marca in obj["modelli"]:
                brand=obj["modelli"][marca]
                for serie in brand:
                        ser=brand[serie]
                        for modello in ser:
                                model=modello
                                marca = marca.strip()
                                modello = modello.strip()
                                serie = serie.strip()
                                print oem,";",marca,";",serie,";",modello
```

It should just cycle an array from a json var and print the output in csv format, but i still get the string containing one withespace at the begin and at the end of each variable (oem, marca, serie, modello) like this

```
KD-CH884 ; Dell ;  ; 966
```

This is my very first script in python, i've just followed some simple directives, so i'm missing something or what?
Any guess?

Comment: Try
 `print ";".join((oem, marca, serie, modello))` in the last line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print` statement is putting in that whitespace.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) here:

> A space is written before each object is (converted and) written,
>   unless the output system believes it is positioned at the beginning of
>   a line.

Use `';'.join(...)` instead.

Comment: `...` here should be an iterable, so the example should look like:
`";".join((oem, marca, serie, modello))`

Comment: Thank for the help, unfortunally i didn't think to looking for the print function docs.

Answer (score 1):

Python is actually stripping the whitespaces out. Its just the print statement:

```
print oem,";",marca,";",serie,";",modello
```

.. that is reintroducing the spaces. Try concatenating the variables and display them.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
print "%s;%s;%s;%s" % (oem,marca,serie,modello)
```

or

```
print ";".join([oem,marca,serie,modello])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
';'.join(filter(None, [oem, marca, serie, modello]))
```

It will only place the semicolon between two existing strings.  If a variable holds the empty string after being stripped '', filtering the None will take it out of the list.

Comment: although learning about `filter` is good, this solution is bad if for example he's trying to store the output as csv

Comment: filter seems interesting, i will take a look at it